# Is it possible to find the original sequence of integers from its prefix sums and suffix sums?

Tags: java, algorithm

Is there a way to find the initial sequence from its prefix sums and suffix sums?

Prefix sum at `i`th position is the sum of all elements from beginning to `i`th position.

Suffix sum at `i`th position is the sum of all elements from last to `i`th position in reverse order.

For an example, the combined (prefix sums and suffix sums) sequence is as follows:

```
{1, 3, 3, 5, 6, 6}
```

The initial sequence was: `{1, 2, 3}`

Prefix sums: `{1, 3, 6}`, Suffix sums: `{6, 5, 3}`

In combined: `{1, 3, 3, 5, 6, 6}`

May be in some cases there are multiple possibilities.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that the sequence is in ascending order? Can there be negative numbers in the sequence?

Comment: If you reverse the array, you will get the same combined set

Comment: This is a live question from Codechef January Contest. Wait until the comp ends.

Comment: This problem appears to be from an ongoing programming contest: https://www.codechef.com/JAN20B/problems/CHEFPSA. Please always credit the original source where you originally encountered the problem.  Don't ask questions from a live contest: that is considered cheating.

Comment: I've no idea that this question belongs to any contest, I am not participating any contest for a year. The question came to mind while I was trying to answer another question in this site. @D.W.

Comment: @ManojBanik, it'd be great if you linked to the other question to give the motivation to your question.

Answer (score 3):

Prefix Sum:

---

```
  original array : {1, 2, 3}
  prefix sum array : {1, 1+2, 1+2+3}
```

Suffix Sum:

---

```
  original array : {1, 2, 3}
  suffix sum array : {3+2+1, 3+2, 3}
```

As per your question, the combined array seems to be sorted. Therefore

---

```
 Let combined array be c[] = {1, 1+2, 3, 3+2, 1+2+3, 3+2+1} = {1, 3, 3, 5, 6, 6}
```

Now, finding the original sequence:

1. If original array has n elements then combined array will have 2*n elements
2. Split the array like array1 = {c[0], c[2], c[4]} and array2 = {c[1], c[3], c[5]}
3. array1 will now have prefix sum and array2 will have suffix sum
4. Now array1 is sufficient to find the original sequence (as combined array is sorted 
   as per your question). Therefore original array would be {c[0], c[2]-c[0], c[4]-c[2]}

---

```
int length = combined_array.length/2;
int []prefix_breakup = new int[length];
int []original = new int[length];

for(int i=0; i<length ; i++){
    if( i%2 == 0 ){
        prefix_breakup[i] = combined_array[i];
    } 
}

original[0] = prefix_breakup[0];

for(int i=1; i<length ; i++){
    original[i] = prefix_breakup[i] - prefix_breakup[i-1];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, what if the initial sequence contain negative numbers,  {5, -2, 7} generates the combined sums {3 5 5 7 10 10}, but will produce {3, 2, 5} according to your logic.

Comment: Manoj, I think if in the combined array the elements are sorted then it is not possible, other wise a binary search tree could solve this problem. So in this case my logic will not work.

Comment: Or, we can think to produce all possible initial sequences, since from the combined sums it is impossible to tell the exact one.